# How can I fill textbox value from javascript and execute the remaining code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi all I have written a javascript function where I pass 3 arguments from code behind I am having a text box, button and a text box on my form on leaving text box or clicking the button when the cursor is inside the first text box I would like to fill the second text box from the script I call the script inside the button as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getEndDate2(noOfWeeks, sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay, DateStart) {
            // My script code
  }

<asp:TextBox ID="txtString" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Pass" OnClick="btnClick_Click" />

protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int noOfweeks = Convert.ToInt16(txtString.Text);;
    string sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay = "Friday";
    string DateStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString();
    btnClick.Attributes.Add("onClick", "getEndDate2('" + noOfweeks + "','" + sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay + "','" + DateStart + "');");
     // Some code to insert the values to database
 }
```

But unable to display the value in the second text box can some one help me how can I call that script Immediately after losing focus on from the text box

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about the problem here, but from what I assume, you can attach a function of the first textbox or the button on

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getEndDate2(noOfWeeks, sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay, DateStart) {
            // My script code
    //then here an ajax call to the insertDB function

  }

<asp:TextBox ID="txtString" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Pass" OnClick="btnClick_Click" />

protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int noOfweeks = Convert.ToInt16(txtString.Text);;
    string sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay = "Friday";
    string DateStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString();
    btnClick.Attributes.Add("onClick", "getEndDate2('" + noOfweeks + "','" + sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay + "','" + DateStart + "');");
     REMOVE THE+IS CODE TO next function // Some code to insert the values to database
 }

protected void insertDB() // this should be accessible to ajax call
{
      insert to db function

}
```

if you can provide the HTML I can help more. I hope this helps

Comment: Hi `Hari` I attached that too like ` int noOfweeks = 3;
    string sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay = "Friday";
    string DateStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString();
    textBox1.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "getEndDate2('" + noOfweeks + "','" + sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay + "','" + DateStart + "');");`

Comment: okay, but the function getenddate2 function is going to assign the text to the second text box, right ? how are you achieving that ? I believe there is only some small problem which we are missing. The HTML, js code will make it more clear. if possible post them

Comment: check now I added HTML and script

Comment: yeah i saw that, let me take a look. Everything seems to be fine !!

Comment: function getEndDate2(noOfWeeks, sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay, DateStart) {
  // your code script code
   
  // at this point you have the value to be assigned in say     
  //"str_val_to_assign"
  document.getElementById('#txtString').value = str_val_to_assign;
  }

does this help ? Take a look at the view source also, it may be getting screwed when getting rendered in the browser.

Comment: Hi every thing works fine but the server side functionality of btn_Click with the remaining code `// Some code to insert the values to database` is getting executed, what I mean to say is the complete code is working but what I need is I would like to display the text form javascript then I need to execute the DB code

Comment: oh, okay. like you want to run show the text in the text box and then do the remaining db insertions ? then I will suggest like
you can add the js function to show the textbox value, then after that you have to use the postback from there or from there an ajax call. The problem here is the js works on the browser and the c# in the server, right ? So as of now it will work only first c# and then js.

Comment: Yeah exactly how can I avoid this any help

Comment: okay you can go like this
1.Attach the js function as you do now
2.Remove the DB insertion code from the current event listener and make it another function.
3.Make it accessible through the ajax request
4.In the js function, add an ajax call to the db insertion function 
after the text is show in textbox.

so in that way, you can avoid the refreshment of the page and do the insertion while you insert. But I know, there could be some unavailability of the variables and all, but they are totally fixable by logic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26002/discussion-between-learner-and-hari)

Answer (score 0):

call the function OnClientClick event of the button by few changes in the function by taking two hidden fields and getting them in the script

```
hdn.Value = "Friday";
hdn1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString();
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" OnClientClick="getEndDate2();" runat="server" Text="Pass" OnClick="btnClick_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getEndDate2(){
        var noOfweeks = "";
        var sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay = "";
        var DateStart = "";
        noOfweeks = document.getElementById("txtString").value;
        sEmployeeWeeklyOfDay = document.getElementById("hdn").value;
        DateStart = document.getElementById("hdn1").value;
        // Your script remaining code
}
</script>
```